# Finding all topological orders

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have to make an algorithm that finds all the topological orders(using predecessor counting) and the highest cost paths and their costs between 2 pairs of vertices. My algorithm looks like this for now:

```
 def topologicalSort(self):
        sorted = []
        count = {}
        q = deque()
        for x in self.parseX():
            count[x] = self.innerDegree(x)
            if count[x] == 0:
                q.append(x)
        while len(q) > 0:
            x = q.popleft()
            sorted.append(x)
            for y in self.parseNout(x):
                count[y] -= 1
                if count[y] == 0:
                    q.append(y)
        return sorted
```

And the highest cost path algorithm is good:

```
    def highestCostPath(self, sorted, source, destination):
        distances = [-math.inf] * len(sorted)
        prev = [-1] * len(sorted)
        distances[source] = 0
        for vertex in sorted:
            if vertex == destination:
                break
            for outboundNeighbours in self.parseNout(vertex):
                if distances[outboundNeighbours] < distances[vertex] + self.Cost(vertex, outboundNeighbours):
                    distances[outboundNeighbours] = distances[vertex] + self.Cost(vertex, outboundNeighbours)
                    prev[outboundNeighbours] = vertex
        return distances[destination], prev[:]
```

It works fine but the problem is that is will find only one topological order. And my question would be: How can I make it to find all the topological orders?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica. I am afraid that statements in the comment above is incorrect. Or misleading at least. Consider the partial order $p>x$, $p>y$ and $y>z$. No two elements can belong to the same equivalent class in a way that fits the description.

Comment: Backtracking is needed to find all the topological orders.

Comment: @JohnL. Ah, I see. Thanks for correcting me!